# how to add html table dynamically and values inserted into database in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

`php` code for adding html table dyanamically is given below, 
but it fails to insert all values in database

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    require_once("include/config.php");
    $num=$_POST['n'];
    $i=0;
    if( isset($_POST['submit']) )
    {
    $num=$_POST['n'];
    echo "ji".$num;
    for($i=0;$i<=$num; $i++)
    {
       $j=addslashes($_POST['t1'][$i]);
       $m=addslashes($_POST['t2'][$i]);
       $sql= "INSERT INTO ba (a,b)values('$j','$m');"; 
       $res =mysqli_query($con,$sql) ;
       $i++;
       if($res)
       {
        echo "<script>alert('Family details submitted successfully');document.location.href='b.php';</script>"; 
        }
        else
        {
        echo "<script>alert('Error. Please Retry');document.location.href='b.php';</script>";
        }
       }
    }

?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    </head>

    <body>
    <form name="sdfs" method="post">
    <table border="3">
    <?php

    while($i<$num)
    {

        echo "<tr><td><input type='text' id='t1[$i]' name='t1[$i]'></td><td>
        <input type='text' id='t2[$i]' name='t2[$i]'></td>
        ";
            $i++;
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
    </tr>

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

value of num is obtained from another page ....
Alternate values are inserting in db...but i want to insert all values to database that obtained through form
pls find a solution for this problem.......................

Comment: please remove unnecessary space

Comment: it is because you are changing location after one insertion by using `document.location.href='b.php'` remove this and you will able to add all data

Comment: No.... Even though I remove it,it does not work

Comment: try printing query error

Comment: No query error.... I think problem is in looop

Comment: comment both ` // echo "<script` and then try ?

Comment: Only first value is inserting in db .....